Why is the value of b in van der Waals equation greater than volume of water
I have been told that $b$ of water in the van der Waals equation is $\pu{0.03 L/mol}$.
And volume of water at STP is $\pu{0.018 L}$.
If we use these values, we get $V-b$ as negative in the van der Waals equation which gives negative pressure.
How's this even possible?
And I knew that we can apply van der Waals equation to real gases and liquids too.
Tell me if I am wrong anywhere in my understanding.

Some textbooks use strange term "Vanderwaal" (or other variants) as a distorted Dutch family name "van der Waals" (from Waals) of Johannes Diderik van der Waals, the famous physical chemist in late 19th century.

The van der Waals equation
$$\left(p+a\left(\frac{n}{V}\right)^2\right)\left(V-nb\right)=nRT$$
is not much useful for liquids, nor for gases near their critical conditions or at very high pressures.
The $b$ parameter, computed from V=f(p,T,n) or from the critical conditions, is theoretical construct, being four times bigger than the total volume of $\pu{1 mol}$ of assumed spherical molecules. This molar volume of molecules is not the same as the molar volume of the liquid. As the latter has non-spherical molecules and additional inter-molecular space.
Near this $b$ volume, where there is three times more free space, compared to the volume of a molecule, molecules of the model mutually lock, cannot move freely and the pressure raises rapidly.
To comment your particular data, the van der Waals model assumes $\ce{H2O}$ molecules are spherical and their own molar volume is $\dfrac{b}{4} = \dfrac{\pu{30 mL}}{4} = \pu{7.5 mL}$. The difference $\pu{18 mL} - \pu{7.5 mL} = \pu{10.5 mL}$ is then assumed being the free space between molecules within $\pu{1 mol}$ of liquid water.

Addressing the comment:
The parameter $b$ should not be considered as the molar volume, but as "the volume excluded from the space for free molecular motion.
For the van der Waals spherical model of real gas, for the volume of each sphere, there must be at least 3 times such a volume as the  intermolecular space, together 4 times the one volume of molecular spheres.
$$V_\text{tot} = 4N_\text{A} \cdot (\frac 43 \pi \cdot r^3)$$
If it is less than 4 times, molecules cannot pass around their neighbors, but are being bounced back and such a substance could not behave as a gas any more.
I have seen some geometrical reasoning a sphere can have only one other sphere in a close touch inside of a sphere of a double diameter, which has eight times bigger volume than one sphere and four times than both spheres.
It could be interesting 3D geometry homework to derive loose enough regular arrangement of the balls where such a passing is possible, and then calculating percentage the balls occupy.
E.g. imagine the tightest ball arrangement of balls in a single layer in a triangular net. But no ball from other layers can pass through the opening between them. The layer must get loose enough for a ball able to pass through the center of the ball triangle. If you then calculate the space filling factor of the balls, it is far from 100%. It was not 100% even at the tightest arraignment (it is i guess about 74%).

I didn't understand why that volume is four times the total volume and there is three Times more free space

See the A update.

But what about the pressure, if we substitute the above a and b values for water , I get pressure negative why so

You apply the equation of the model out of its validity scope. The molar volume of water is obviously smaller that the volume excluded from the free molecular motion. Water molecules cannot  move freely passing each other as molecules of gas can. / the model expects V_m of the gas (not liquid) is always greater than b.
